# Facebook Integration in Wordpress

Tags: php, facebook, wordpress

I'm trying to integrate Facebook API into Wordpress. It seems I can't include the API when I edit the pages directly in PHP:

```
$facebook = new Facebook(array(
  'appId'  => '?',
  'secret' => '?',
  'cookie' => true,
));

$session = $facebook->getSession();
```

Always returns a blank session unless I put the code in the wp-blog-header.php or index.php for the Wordpress install itself. I believe this is because it's trying to set cookies and can't at this point. Does anyone know how I can get this to work? I really don't want to have to create some stupid work around.

Comment: Where are you putting it now?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely sure that it's because cookies haven't been loaded yet. But try this:

Add the following to your theme's `functions.php` file (the 'init' action should make this get called long after cookies and such have loaded):

```
<?php 
function facebook_setup() {
 global $facebook;

  $facebook = new Facebook(array(
    'appId'  => '?',
    'secret' => '?',
    'cookie' => true,
  ));
}
add_action('init', 'facebook_setup');
?>
```

And then calling that global variable in your templates. e.g.

```
<?php
  global $facebook;
  $me = $facebook->api('/me');
  print_r($me);
?>
```

I'm not sure if this will fix the issue. Depending on how you setup [Facebook's Oauth flow](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/), there might be another cause to your problem.